# Error when running python script through SSH

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I am using Gotify to send a message to my phone from a raspberry pi. I have a script for a laser tripwire that sends the message when triggered.

CURRENT ERROR

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Projects $ Tripwire.py 


from: can't read /var/mail/gpiozero

from: can't read /var/mail/time

./Laser_Tripwire.py: 4: ./Laser_Tripwire.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

The python script

```
from gpiozero import LightSensor

from time import sleep

import requests

ldr = LightSensor(4)

while True:

    sleep(.5)

    print (ldr.value)

    if ldr.value < .5:

        requests.post("http://192.168.1.33/message?token=Ah9v9xauxuhmEJ_",

                    json={"title":"Laser Tripwire",

                    "priority": 4,

                    "message":"The alarm has been triggered!"})

        sleep(10)

    else:

        ()


The message goes through whenever I run it just on the pi but when I'm SSH trying to run it I will get the error.
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it looks like your program is being run by a shell, not by Python. Hence the confusing messages about mail — `from` is a command to check for new mail! You need to tell the shell (or the kernel) that your program is a Python program. Either run it with `python3 Tripwire.py` or add a so-called "[shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)" line at the very beginning.